# Visualise data at an interval of minutes in highcharts timeseries

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highcharts for visualization of irregular time interval data(i.e. irregular time series chart). It shows data at an interval of day only but I want to plot it minute wise. I am working on twitter data streaming so, it's important to plot per minute wise because of high tweet traffic and to help as fast as possible in order to responsd and analyse for disaster management.

My date format till minute is:

```
[[Date.UTC(2014,11,07,08,11),1],[Date.UTC(2014,11,07,08,11),23],[Date.UTC(2014,11,07,09,11),26],[Date.UTC(2014,11,07,09,11),22],[Date.UTC(2014,11,07,09,11),9],[Date.UTC(2014,11,07,09,11),18],[Date.UTC(2014,11,07,09,11),13],[Date.UTC(2014,11,07,09,11),9],[Date.UTC(2014,11,07,09,11),2],[Date.UTC(2014,11,07,09,11),15],[Date.UTC(2014,11,07,09,11),10],[Date.UTC(2014,11,07,09,11),20],[Date.UTC(2014,11,07,09,11),2]]
```

and the fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/shumanbaral/z3pL4LpL/2/

I have been trying this for days.

Comment: It is not an interval of day, it is between 8:11 and 9:11 (an hour). And can you please explain more about your problem? do you want the tick intervals of minutes? if so, see this for two second interval: http://jsfiddle.net/z3pL4LpL/4/

Comment: Thank you very much @RaeenHashemi for your help. Actually I had duplicate dates with same number of count and the data were staked in chart because of my mistake in the sql query. Now, it works for me. Also thank you for reminding me about the tick interval. It solved the half problem.

Comment: So at this moment it works properly or not ?

Comment: Yes, @SebastianBochan it works properly on fiddle but I am still to implement it on server side. I will implement as soon as the postgresql server problem is solved. Thank you for your concern.